# Can I use my Lumia to pay for things using NFC in Sweden?

Tags: nfc, tap-to-pay

There have been articles around for a long time where people talk about paying for things with NFC in the stores. Is it possible in Sweden using a Lumia?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You can use [SEQR](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=7c25ac1c-dfb7-4cd5-b040-fdeef6ab09a8) to pay for things using NFC (and QR) in some stores in Sweden.